# Flash Builder plugins for formatting ActionScript and MXML code

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

Anything like that out there now? I know there was a rather buggy formatter for FB 3, but how about a mature code formatter for FB 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FlexFormatter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexformatter/) is the only one I'm aware.

I bet there are a lot of Eclipse based formatters that would work on Flex/AS projects, though.

Comment: Wasn't aware they had updated that for FB4 (it appears that is has been)... but wow, doesn't Sourceforge suck these days? 99% of projects don't bother using all the built in stuff so half the time you end up aimlessly wandering a mostly-default template looking for things as simple as a project description, compatibility info, docs, downloads, etc... geez.

Comment: I thought SourceForge was always that way honestly.  Details on Open Source projects often seems hit or miss.

Comment: Probably, but I think it's gotten a little extra bloated over time. At least it feels that way. Dunno why they don't let projects opt in to specific features, instead of wasting thousands of visitors time (and bandwidth!) clicking through empty templates!